# Jquery refresh without button press

Tags: jquery, timer

We have the following jquery which get data from the backend .php script. Everything works fine. What need help on is how to do this without the button press but say for every 30 seconds or 1 minutes interval to do the same thing.Below is our current script?

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchBtn").click(function(){
     $(this).attr('src', 'images/searching.png');

     var data = $(this).val();

     var dateFrom=document.getElementById("beginDate").value;
     dateFromArray=dateFrom.split("/");     
     var myDateFrom=new Date(dateFromArray[2],dateFromArray[1],dateFromArray[0]);

     var dateTo=document.getElementById("endDate").value;
     dateToArray=dateTo.split("/");                           
     var myDateTo=new Date(dateToArray[2],dateToArray[1],dateToArray[0]);

     mysqlDateFrom=dateFromArray[2]+"-"+dateFromArray[1]+"-"+dateFromArray[0];
     mysqlDateTo=dateToArray[2]+"-"+dateToArray[1]+"-"+dateToArray[0];     


     $.post('getBK.php', {b: mysqlDateFrom,e: mysqlDateTo}, function(data){
          $("#searchBtn").attr('src', 'images/search.png');
            $('#dbData').html(data);            
         }
     );
   }
   );
 }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Use setInterval(hadler, timeOut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

function myfunc(){
 $("#searchBtn").attr('src', 'images/searching.png');

 var data = $("#searchBtn").val();

 var dateFrom=document.getElementById("beginDate").value;
 dateFromArray=dateFrom.split("/");     
 var myDateFrom=new Date(dateFromArray[2],dateFromArray[1],dateFromArray[0]);

 var dateTo=document.getElementById("endDate").value;
 dateToArray=dateTo.split("/");                           
 var myDateTo=new Date(dateToArray[2],dateToArray[1],dateToArray[0]);

 mysqlDateFrom=dateFromArray[2]+"-"+dateFromArray[1]+"-"+dateFromArray[0];
 mysqlDateTo=dateToArray[2]+"-"+dateToArray[1]+"-"+dateToArray[0];     


 $.post('getBK.php', {b: mysqlDateFrom,e: mysqlDateTo}, function(data){
  $("#searchBtn").attr('src', 'images/search.png');
    $('#dbData').html(data);            
  }
 );
  }

  myfunc();
  setInterval( function(){ myfunc(); } , 30000 );  

   });
 </script>
```

Comment: we do not want to have the button anymore meaning that on the page load it should start calling the backend script on the said interval

Comment: the function is working just for the benefit of the rest this line should be removed

Comment: Another thing is that it does not start immediately but need to wait for say 30 seconds how to overcome this ?

Comment: It runs only once but twice it call the function

Comment: spelling mistake corrected, try again, this updated code will work perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `setInterval()`

```
$(function(){
    // set interval
    var tid = setInterval(mycode, 30000);
    function mycode() {
      // place your button click logic over here
    }
    function abortTimer() { // to be called when you want to stop the timer
      clearInterval(tid);
    }

});
```

Comment: I just put this code under this  $(document).ready(function() {  }

Answer (score 1):

To have the POST to PHP run automatically when the DOM is loaded, then use the `setInterval()` function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        // Do something every 30 seconds
        $.post('getBK.php', {b: mysqlDateFrom,e: mysqlDateTo}, function(data){
            $("#searchBtn").attr('src', 'images/search.png');
                $('#dbData').html(data);            
            }
        );
    }, 30000);
);
```

Note: the second value of `setInterval()` is the time for the interval in milliseconds (so 30000 for 30 seconds or 60000 for 1 minute).

Comment: How will this function be called ? Will it automatically run ?

Comment: If you put it inside the `$(document).ready`, then yes it will be run automatically when the DOM is loaded.